# BorderWidth is getting added with view react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a view with `LeftArrowTriangle`, `View` and `RightArrowTriangle`, but whenever I am trying add content inside `View`, I am getting 1px borderWidth either on left or right side of view.

[image]

Here is my styleSheet for body content and left/right triangle

```
bodyContent: ({ primaryColor }, theme) => ({ padding: 4, backgroundColor: primaryColor, alignItems: 'center', overflow: 'hidden' }),
  triangleRight: ({ color }, theme) => ({
    height: ARROW_TRANGLE_HEIGHT,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: ARROW_TRAINGLE_WIDTH,
    borderBottomWidth: 13,
    borderTopWidth: 13,
    borderLeftColor: color,
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent'
  }),
  triangleLeft: ({ color }, theme) => ({
    height: ARROW_TRANGLE_HEIGHT,
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRightWidth: ARROW_TRAINGLE_WIDTH,
    borderBottomWidth: 13,
    borderTopWidth: 13,
    borderRightColor: color,
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent'
  })
```

Comment: Have you used the inspector to look in the dom and see which element those pixels belong to? We can't see how these views are constructed, it could be some implicit margin or padding (like on text).

Comment: Yes, I have checked it is not because of implicit margin or padding. However, this is coming because of content in the <View />